# How to improve baking quality in cycles render engine?

Tags: texture-baking

I'm trying to bake a texture with the size of **256*256** px but I get an awful result, so I increased the baking size into **1024*1024** px and the output was much better than before. The problem is that I need the texture to be **256*256** px that looks as good as a **1K** texture resolution, because I'm going to use it in a mobile game, so large images will not work in such games. So is there a way to enhance the baking without increasing the pixels count?

[image: this is the 1K baking which looks good]
 [image: this is the 256*256 px that looks bad]
[image: this is my UV unwrap]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried resizing the 1k image down to 256 in a image editor?

You not gonna get a very sharp image with such a low image resolution, I would try to manually unwrap the the object and give areas that need more detail more UV space on the image. 
You can also try adding adding UV's on top of each other if they share a identical texture on the object, so instead of 2 separate UV's there's just 2 UV's on top of each other sharing the same image. :)

Comment: yes i have tried to downscale it, but the end result wasn't good either.And for the other suggestion i placed the UVs on top of each other and scaled them up to give them more space, so the end result has improved a little bit, but it's still not as good as a 1K. Any other suggestions? @Ravenman 13

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
There's not much more you can do without a larger image. You could look into image formats that offer good image compression so the higher res file takes up less space. I would look into image formats that offer good image compression, to allow you to have a higher resolution image but at a smaller file size.